# List of WebParts that support Audience Targetting

Tags: 2010, web-part

How do I get a list of WebParts that support Audience Targetting? Is there any documentation?

I have a audience created and I can see their memberships after compiling. However, web parts like Content editor, summary link, list view etc not showing any options for audience targetting. Am I missing anything?

Comment: These webparts do support audience targeting. Are you looking in the Advanced section of the Web Part tool pane?

Comment: I was looking at advanced panel. I realize my web app was not subscribing user profile service. Once I enabled it, target audience appeared in webpart properties.

Comment: Close the Question then with your answer mate :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize my web app was not subscribing user profile service. Once I enabled it, target audience appeared in webpart properties.

I hope MS developers instead disabled that control in the tool pane with a note like "control is disabled because user profile service is not subscribed" :-)